# Is there a real proxy written in PHP or, what would I have to do to implement one?

Tags: php, proxy

I have been looking around on the web for a PHP proxy script and I can't find any. All I keep finding are scripts that download pages and edit `src` and `href` attributes in the HTML and, require me to browse to whatever website they're installed on. I don't need this, I need a real proxy listening on a port that I can set my browser to route all it's requests to.

What I'm looking to do is:

1. run a PHP script that will listen on some port of my own computer
2. configure my web browser to use localhost:port as a proxy
3. have the PHP script serve the page to my browser

All the so called proxy scripts written in PHP, that I have found, will fail miserably if the page requested uses `XMLHttpRequest` to fetch content because they won't see that request at all. No amount of link rewriting will solve the issue short of injecting some clever JavaScript that is unnecessary with a real proxy.

What I want in the end, is to have access to the requests and responses going back and forth between my browser and some remote server. I want to be able to use my browser's support for JavaScript, cookies, flash, etc. Basically, I want to have programmatic access to all the communication so I can analyze or manipulate it using PHP.

So, the questions are

- Have I missed the real proxy implemented in PHP because of all the noise in my search results?
- If there isn't a real proxy in PHP I would like to try making one. Are there resources online to help me learn what exactly I should do? (note, I RTM religiously: looking more for caveats and architecture of a basic proxy)

Links are appreciated. I know there are several MITM proxies out there but I want one in PHP.

I don't know if maybe I could do something with [PHP's built-in webserver](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) but I'll mess with that as well.

**UPDATE**

I've got a router script for the PHP built in webserver that is beginning to show promise. I can fire up the webserver and tell my web browser to use it as a proxy. The router script I've made differentiates between local and external resources and gives an easy way of handling either case. The only problem I have is with https. The server reports `Invalid Request (Malformed HTTP Request)`. I think that means this server won't do https at all with just scripts and settings. I don't know. Maybe I'll be able to do it with Apache but transparently proxying https sounds hard, especially if I want to alter the data before it hits my browser.

**AtropaToolbox/php_router/router.php**
The router script my PHP built in webserver is pointed at, pulls in the actual classes from other files.

```
<?php
require_once('AtropaToolbox/php_proxy/proxy.php');

$proxy = new atropa_proxy();

if($proxy->process_request() === false) {
    return false;
}

?>
```

**AtropaToolbox/php_proxy/proxy.php**
Extends atropa_mod_proxy to redefine the handlers.

```
<?php
require_once('AtropaToolbox/php_proxy/mod_proxy.php');

class atropa_proxy extends atropa_mod_proxy 
{
    protected function local_resource_handler() {
        return false;
    }

    protected function external_resource_handler() {
        $ext = $this->get_page();
        //echo '<pre>' . print_r($ext, true) . '</pre>';
        //$ext['page'] = preg_replace('/<a /', '<p ', $ext['page']);
        $this->show_page($ext);
    }
}
?>
```

**AtropaToolbox/php_proxy/mod_proxy.php**
The generic router script

```
<?php
/**
 * Rev. 1 Atropa mod_proxy for php built in webserver
 */
class atropa_mod_proxy
{
    protected function is_external_resource() {
        $host = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_HOST);
        if(isset($host) && $host !== $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected function local_resource_handler() {
        return false;
    }

    protected function external_resource_handler() {
        $ext = $this->get_page();
        $this->show_page($ext);
    }

    public function process_request() {
        if($this->is_external_resource()) {
            return $this->external_resource_handler();
        } else {
            return $this->local_resource_handler();
        }
    }

    public function get_request_headers() {
        $arr = array();
        foreach($_SERVER as $svar => $sval) {
            if(substr($svar, 0, 4) === 'HTTP') {
                $svar = substr($svar, 5);
                $svar = preg_replace('/_/', ' ', $svar);
                $svar = ucwords(strtolower($svar));
                $svar = preg_replace('/ /', '-', $svar);
                $arr[$svar] = $sval;
            }
        }
        return $arr;
    }

    public function pack_request_headers($headers_array) {
        $packed = '';
        foreach($headers_array as $header_name => $header_value) {
            $packed .= $header_name . ': ' . $header_value . "\r\n";
        }
        return $packed;
    }

    public function echo_response_headers($http_response_header_array) {
        foreach($http_response_header_array as $val) {
            if(strpos(strtolower($val), 'connection') !== 0) {
                header($val);
            }
        }
    }

    protected function get_page() {
        $request_headers = $this->get_request_headers();
        $request_headers = $this->pack_request_headers($request_headers);
        $method = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
        $scheme = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_SCHEME);
        $opts = array(
            $scheme => array(
                'method' => $method,
                'header' => $request_headers
            )
        );
        if(count($_POST) > 0) {
            $content = http_build_query($_POST);
            $opts[$scheme]['content'] = $content;
        }
        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        $ext = array();
        $ext['page'] = file_get_contents($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], false, $context);
        $ext['http_response_header'] = $http_response_header;
        return $ext;
    }

    protected function show_page($ext) {
        header_remove();
        $this->echo_response_headers($ext['http_response_header']);
        echo $ext['page'];
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please read on [Socket Programming with PHP](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Socket-Programming-With-PHP/) and [An Introduction to Sockets in PHP](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/An-Introduction-to-Sockets-in-PHP/). You will be running a [PHP Daemon](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/) to make PHP listen to a port and process all the requests.

In order to do this, you might want to look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/poxy/ so you can base your PHP Daemon there. You also have to learn how proxies communicate with clients. Poxy is a web-based application, you enter a URL and it loads it for you. It wouldn't allow you to listen to ports and it's not a php daemon so you will have to do a lot of coding for your PHP daemon proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the links on socket programming. :D

Comment: I don't really want a so called "web proxy" where I surf the net in some kind of frame and it rewrites all the links. I could do that with batch files... I want to make a real proxy, maybe using PHP's built in webserver, the right router script, and curl. I don't know if that will work.

Comment: XD Awesome article. I'm definitely going to mess around with those ideas more. I've been tinkering with the PHP built in webserver today and came up with a router script that is beginning to work. I am able to tell firefox that my server is my proxy and do what every other PHP proxy script has done so far, use file_get_contents to echo back a crummy version of the page. XD I'll do some more testing later tonight to see how hard it will be to get it to recognize mime types and such. I'll update my question with the code I've got so far, it's really short.